# Three.js - How to update vertices in a THREE.Points (or THREE.ParticleSystem)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm seeing examples that mention about setting the vertices' (i.e. `THREE.Vector3`) objects `.velocity` and seeing the particleSystem's `geometry.__dirtyVertices` to `true`.

But I am not seeing either of these properties.
I am using definitely typed definition for three.js revision 75.

If all else fails I will likely resort to manually updating all vertices based on their respective velocity. But I really don't want to do that.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet and what you are trying to acomplish? AFAIK there is no in-built velocity feature, you have to write your own shader that would take velocity of a particle into account(custom geometry attribute)

Comment: I basically had to update the vertices (x, y, z) components and then call the verticesNeedUpdate = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;` is for pre-r49, in later versions you need to use:

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Check this **[How to update things](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates)** reference document to find more details on how to update things.